Looping a configparser-object and convert to class objects
i have this class-instance:
class classValve:
    def __init__(self, gpio, name, mode):
        self.gpio = gpio
        self.name = name
        self.mode = mode
        self.valve_open = GPIO.LOW
        self.valve_close = GPIO.HIGH
        self.delay = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        self.duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
        self.start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
        self.stop_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc) + self.duration
        self.waterflow = 0
        self.rain = False
        self.water_pressure = 0        
        self.config_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), self.name+".conf")
        GPIO.setup(self.gpio, self.mode)
        GPIO.output(self.gpio, self.valve_close)

for fail-saving the current status, i use the configparser in the following maner
    def load_config (self):
        parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
        parser.optionxform = str  # make option names case sensitive
        found = parser.read(self.config_file)
        if not found:
            #raise ValueError('No config file found!')
            pass
        print("read config {}".format(self.config_file))
        for key, value in parser.items(self.name):
            try:
                value = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(value)              
                if(isinstance(value, datetime.datetime)):
                    setattr(self, key, value)
            except Exception:
                try:
                    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(value,"%H:%M:%S")
                    value = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
                    setattr(self, key, value)
                except Exception:
                    try:
                        value = int(value)
                        setattr(self, key, value)
                    except Exception:
                        try:
                            value = float(value)
                            setattr(self, key, value)
                        except Exception:
                            try:
                                value = bool(value == 'True')
                            except Exception:
                                setattr(self, key, value)
            print(type(value), value)
        del parser 


    def save_config (self):
        parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
        parser.optionxform = str  # make option names case sensitive
        parser.add_section(self.name)

        #parser[self.name] = list(self.__dict__.iteritems())
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            parser.set(self.name, str(key), str(value))

        print("save config {}".format(self.config_file))
        # Writing our configuration file to '%self.name%.conf'
        with open(self.config_file, 'w') as configfile:
             parser.write(configfile)


The save_config() function output culminate in something like this:
[beet01]
gpio = 21
name = beet01
mode = 0
valve_open = 0
valve_close = 1
delay = 23:59:59
duration = 0:01:00
start_datetime = 2024-06-01 08:51:02.742465+00:00
stop_datetime = 2024-06-01 08:52:02.742465+00:00
waterflow = 0
rain = False
water_pressure = 0
config_file = /mnt/wd/beet01.conf

After reloading I have to convert strings to datetime, timedelta, integers, etc. I use the try/exception waterfall-loop in load_config(). But it is not very robust to failures. Is there a better approach?

maybe you should use continue (before except  Exception) and then you don't have to nest try/except - and code can be more readable.

comparison value == 'True' gives boolean value True or False and you don't have to convert it to bool()
